# How can I convert an HTMLcollection that contains the children of a div into an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, htmlcollection

I am trying to code a puzzle game but now I want to disable a button as long as the puzzle is not solved. I have a board (the place where you can drag and drop the pieces) and the tray (the place where you got the pieces from), as well as a button that brings you to the next puzzle. This is my html code:

```
<div class="board" id="b1"></div>                                                                      
        <br>
        <div class="tray" id = "t1"></div>                                                                       
        <br>

        <a href="./trial2_puppy.html">
            <button class ="startExp2" id ="np_t1" disabled="disabled">Next puzzle</button>
        </a>
```

I also have a JavaScript file that implements the drag and drop functionality (dragging a puzzle piece from the tray onto a position on the board). And I add the id from the piece that was dropped on the board using

```
function dragEnd() {                                                                                //this swaps the selected image with the one that it was dropped on
    if (currTile.src.includes("blank")) {
        return;
    }
    let currImg = currTile.src;
    let otherImg = otherTile.src;
    currTile.src = otherImg;
    otherTile.src = currImg;
    idTile = currTile.id;                                                                           //this adds the id of the puzzle piece to the puzzle piece on the board
    otherTile.id = idTile;
    solveProcedure.push(otherTile);                                                                 //this lets us track the order in which they dragged the elements

}
```

I want to get an array of id's of the current pieces on the board. When the user then clicks on the button, I want to compare whether the order of the puzzle pieces is the same as the solution (see if statement) and if it is the same only then allow them to proceed to the next puzzle.

```
var boarDiv = document.getElementById('b1').children;                                               //this lets us see the images that are currently on the board
            let buttonDis = document.getElementById("np_t1");

            let compBD =  [boarDiv];                                                                //this returns an array of an html collection with length 1
            let img1 = compBD[0][0];
            

            // buttonDis.addEventListener('click', function(boardDiv){
            //     console.log(compBD);
            //     // if (compBD === [img#trial1_tile1, img#trial1_tile2, img#trial1_tile3, img#trial1_tile4, img#trial1_tile5, img#trial1_tile6, img#trial1_tile7, img#trial1_tile8, img#trial1_tile9, img#trial1_tile10, img#trial1_tile11, img#trial1_tile12]){
            //     //     document.getElementById("np_t1").disabled = false;
            //     // };
            // }, false);
```

Now the problem that I am running into is that when I try to convert the html collection `boardDiv` into an array (`compBD`) so that I can compare them, this gives me an array that just holds the html collection, not it's contents (see picture). I tried a couple of different ways, e.g., a for loop,  `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)`, `Array.from(...)` and `[].slice.call(document.getElementById(...).children);` but none of them worked because I couldn't get to the contents of the HTML collection. I think it might be because I take the children of the div but I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

I would really appreciate any input on explanations or solutions to my problem and I hope I could explain well enough what I want my code to do!

Comment: Why not assign a special class name to all elements you want to check on. That way it's as simple as `let arr=[]; document.querySelectorAll('.puzzlepeice').forEach(p => { arr.push(p.id);...`

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea! But that also leaves me with an empty array unfortunately

Comment: could help better if you gave actual example code in a snippet. Like an example of the current HTML structure and the array you are trying to get out of it

Comment: If you want an array of `id` values you can do `Array.from(boardDiv).map(ele => ele.id)`.